# Tempo Estimado de viagem usando dbgeography

Tags: c#

É possível calcular o tempo de viagem estimado entre duas localidades usando dbgeography em C#?

Comment: Bem Vindo SoPt, Você já tentou fazer algo? poste o código para darmos uma olhada.

Comment: Apenas aproximado porque a distancia dada pelo método Distance do dbGeography será uma linha reta.

Comment: Guilherme só tenho a base de dados com dbgeography.

Comment: Você precisa ter outra base com o mapa e informações de como percorrer os trechos do mapa e a rotina para percorrer os trechos e saber a distancia seguindo as ruas e estradas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Depende!

A classe [DbGeographyc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.spatial.dbgeography(v=vs.110).aspx) não foi feito para isso. Ela permite você trabalhar com pontos ou formas (poligons/shapes).

A única forma de conseguir calcular o tempo entre dois pontos, é sabendo qual a distância que você consegue percorrer em tanto tempo.

Você pode perguntar: **Como assim?**

Eu explico.

Com o **DbGeographyc** você consegue apenas a distância entre dois pontos (geralmente em metros), por exemplo:

```
var pointA = string.Format("POINT({1} {0})", latitude1, longitude1);  
var pointB = string.Format("POINT({1} {0})", latitude2, longitude2);

var distanceInMeters = pointA.Distance(pointB);
```

Do ponto **A** ao ponto **B** possui 4000m. Se você percorre 1000m em 10 minutos, irá percorrer os 4000m em 40 minutos. Porém, esse cálculo deve ser feito manualmente por você.

> Vale ressaltar que ele não te da a distância percorrendo ruas/estradas. Ele apenas te retorna a distãncia entre dois pontos, nada mais.